# Taxonomy - how to describe something as plantlike?

Tags: word-choice, latin, taxonomy, scientific-language, plant-physiology

So I'm writing a story that features Chimeras or hybrid creatures, and I'm wondering what I would call a plant based creature. For other things like a spider creature or bird creature I would call it an Arachnid Chimera or an Avian Chimera, but I'm not sure what I would call a plant creature. Would it just be Plant Chimera or is there some Latin word that would work better?

Comment: Not an answer, just a related observation, you might find our sister-site [worldbuilding.se] somewhat interesting and suited to exploring ideas relating to your project. (The same goes for [writing.se]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do "Herbal Chimera" or "Graminous Chimera" just pulling some Latin plant words from Whitaker's Words and Anglicizing them.

Alternatively, an immobile creature could be the "Immotum Chimera."

A silent one could be the "Tacitum or Taciturn Chimera" depending if you prefer more Latin-y or English-y.

All I've studied is Latin, so that's all I can help with. Good luck!